# strpos does not search backwards on negative offset

Tags: php

**Update**: I was looking at docs for `strrpos` thinking it was the docs for `strpos`. Sorry for the dumb mistake.

According to [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php), it says that when you provide a negative value as an offset argument, the function will start that many characters from the end of the string, searching backwards. It even shows this in Example #2. Why then can I not get this code to work properly?

```
$val = strpos('/imports/products/nin_avatar.png', '/', -2);
```

I am trying to get the index of the last forward slash in the string, yet it keeps returning `false`.. I've tried a couple different negative offsets, and none seem to work. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: How does he turn on warnings?  Someone who is having trouble with the `strpos()` docs is probably not going to know how to turn on warnings.

Comment: You've tried negative offsets, but haven't actually read what the manual says about negative offsets

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice I was looking at the docs for strrpos....

Comment: You show `strpos`, yet you refer to the docs of `strrpos` (mind the extra `r`)

Comment: Yes, I looked over that! Sorry everyone!! Stupid mistake

Comment: I made the same mistake and didn't catch it until I saw this.  thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems it works as the OP intended now in a new version of PHP.

---

#### Historical answer

The PHP manual for [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) says...

> Unlike `strrpos()` and `strripos()`, the offset cannot be negative.

[Source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php).

This would be more obvious if you developed with warnings enabled. In your development instance, use something like `error_reporting(E_ALL)`.

Comment: @Shredder Probably not now there are too many answers. I'd never say that about yourself. It's a learning experience. Next time, triple read the documentation :)

Comment: Well, it doesn't! Have you checked the link ("Source") you have suggested? (http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php). There's no any "unlike" and such stuff...

It says clearly: " If the offset is negative, the search will start this number of characters counted from the end of the string."

It's a bug.

Comment: @Apostolos Consider the quote was sourced in 2013. Things sometimes change on the internet.

Comment: Of course things change. But I wonder ... how can the PHP manual in **2013** say that negative offset does not apply to 'strpos()' and the same manual **today** say that it does (when it doesn't)! That's why I say this is a *bug*.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`strrpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) instead of [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the docs says when this question was asked, but if I see the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) now it says negative offset is supported in the latest version  7.1.0, It seems to be a bit of confusion for people like me who had the same issue as like in this question

So as of now the negative offset is supported for strpos**.

** In the version 7.1.0

Answer (score 1):

Support for negative offsets has been added in PHP 7.1.0

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php